# Where was this stock photo (mountains, town) taken?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth

Free stock image (https://www.pexels.com/photo/mist-misty-fog-foggy-7919/), haven't been able to find a description. Does anyone recognize the location?

[image: photo]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like Bled, Slovenia. Here’s a similar photo: [image: Without fog]

Comment: And here's an aerial view: https://www.google.com/maps/@46.3637235,14.0881904,1751m/data=!3m1!1e3

Comment: @NeanDerThal Thanks man. I wasn’t able to get to my phone until now to edit it.